Polyline starts from main world map instead of nearest point
I am using Leaflet map to draw polylines and connect waypoints by clicking on the map.
I also cloned the route and waypoints to the left and right world map.
Sometimes, the route is drawn incorrectly. For example, in the picture below, it connects the last waypoint of the main world map (on the right). The optimal point should be the one from the left world map.
Do I have to manually define which point of which world map is the starting point? And how can I do that?
I am thinking of calculating the distance to find the short polyline but Haversine I use always return same distance of (left start, cur) and (main start, cur).

private void MapOnMouseMove(Map sender, Models.Maps.Events.MouseEvent evt) {
  // Get the last point of the route/polyline: newstart
  // Create new polyline
  var end = new WaypointModel { Latitude = evt.LatLng.Lat, Longitude = evt.LatLng.Lng, IsGreatCircle = true, Number = 1 };
  var _tempRouteLayer = new Polyline { Shape = new PointD[1][] };
  _tempRouteLayer.Shape[0] = (new List<PointD> {   
    new(newStart.Latitude, newStart.Longitude), 
    new(end.Latitude, end.Longitude) 
  }).ToArray();
  MainMap.AddLayer(_tempRouteLayer);
}


left/right map? We see only one map. What are you talking about?

@RoryMcCrossan: thanks for the suggestion. I remove the tags and add the code

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: the map has worldCopyJump turned on. This means you pan to the left or right infinitely. As you can see there are two routes on the world map. These routes are in 2 different world map.
